# Unable to use Babel 7 with Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, babeljs

So, I've tried following Jest's documentation on setting up Babel, including installing `babel-core: 7.0.0-bridge.0` and such, but I've had no luck in getting it to work.

I've tried to dig through their issues on GitHub but many of the solutions there don't work for me, primarily because they are using a `babelrc` file where as I'm using `babel.config.js`, and due to Babel's incredibly hard to read documentation, I cannot for the life figure out how to convert what they are doing in rc files into the js equivalent.

Hopefully someone can provide a solution!

My configuration files are below as well as the error message I'm getting;

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = api => {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  ];

  return {
    presets,
  };
};
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  collectCoverage: true,
  verbose: true,
};
```

Error Msg:

```
Test suite failed to run

    tests/integration/mytest.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import request from 'supertest';
                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
```

Comment: Did you install babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0 and babel-jest? See documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel

Comment: @PatrickHund Hey. Yes I tried installing both of those as well as all the other parts of the docs. Same error. It also says `Note: babel-jest is automatically installed when installing Jest and will automatically transform files if a babel configuration exists in your project.` so I'm not even sure if `babel-jest` is required. Either way whether I install it or not, the same error happens.

Comment: Alright, just wanted to check the basics first 

Comment: same here, looking for this solution for more than 3 hours, last time that I've tried to be in the top of dependencies, waste of time.

Comment: @YuriRamos Since I made this post, they have released Jest 24 which is fully compatible with Babel 7 without any weird bridges or anything. Try upgrading and it should solve your issues! :)